# MySQL v. SQLite for Python based financial web app

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, pandas

I'm building a finance application in Python to do time series analysis on security prices (among other things). The heavy lifting will be done in Python mainly using Numpy, SciPy, and pandas (pandas has an interface for SQLite and MySQL). With a web interface to present results. There will be a few hundred GB of data.

I'm curious what is the better option for database in terms of performance, ease of accessing the data (queries), and interface with Python. I've seen the posts about the general pros and cons of SQLite v. MySQL but I'm looking for feedback that's more specific to a Python application.

Answer (score 10):

The correct answer is [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/). For most platforms it's just as easy to install as MySQL, but it is a better database, and it's especially an improvement on MySQL when it comes to handling large amounts of data, which you are doing.

I wouldn't even begin to consider handling a few hundred GB of data in SQLite.

Comment: Certainly not when "finance" or "analysis" is in the requirements.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Exactly.

Comment: +1. Although while generally agreeing with the answer - OP has stated the reason why he is considering MySQL and SQLite. In his case I'd vote for MySQL.

Comment: I'd also have doubts about SQLite's capability to handle all that many concurrent users. Near as I can tell it uses locking, not something like MVCC.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams certainly not SQLite for finance apps?

Comment: @strimp099: Have you *read* the crack [SQLite is filled with](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is great for embedded databases, but it's not really great for anything that requires access by more than one process at a time. For this reason it cannot be taken seriously for your application.

MySQL is a much better alternative. I'm also in agreement that Postgres would be an even better option.

Answer (score 0):

For many 'research' oriented time series database loads, it is far faster to do as much analysis in the database than to copy the data to a client and analyze it using a regular programming language.  Copying 10G across the network is far slower than reading it from disk.

Relational databases do not natively support time series operations, so generating something as simple as security returns from security prices is either impossible or very difficult in both MySQL and SQLite.

Postgres has windowing operations, as do several other relational-like databases; the trade-off is that that they don't do as many transactions per second.  Many others use K or Q.

The financial services web apps that I've seen used multiple databases; the raw data was stored in 'research' databases that were multiply indexed and designed for flexibility, while the web-apps interacted directly with in-memory caches and higher-speed RDBs; the tradeoff was that data had to be copied from the 'research' databases to the 'production' databases.